# Drawing lines at specified angles

Tags: r

I'm trying to draw lines on a plot with a circle overlay that will divide the circle into 12 parts. The plot has arrows going to the specific points. I have the plot and the circle, but can't figure out how to get the lines. Here's what I tried:

```
library(MASS)
eqscplot(basic.df$Valence, basic.df$Activation, xlim=c(-2,2), ylim=c(-2,2), xlab = "Valence", ylab = "Activation", main = "Affective Content of Pseuke d'Zimra (Basic ANEW)", axes=FALSE, frame.plot = FALSE)
axis(1, pos=0)
axis(2, pos=0)
arrows(0,0,x1=basic.df$Valence, y1 = basic.df$Activation)
symbols(0,0,2, add = TRUE, inches = FALSE, asp = 1)
circumplex.angles <- c(30, 60, 120, 150, 210, 240, 300, 330)
for (i in 1:8) {
   i == 1  
   abline(a=0, b=tan(circumplex.angles[i]))
  }
```

I include the plotting code if you want to replicate what I'm doing completely. (basic.df$Valence has 35 values beteen 0 and 2, and basic.df$Activation has 35 associated values between 0 and -2).

However, the key code is the for-loop.  I'm getting lines at seemingly random angles. (I'd like to show you an image, but I'm having trouble connecting to the server for my website to upload the images. Will edit if I get a connection).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

angles are in radians for the tan function. you can use

```
abline(a=0, b=tan(circumplex.angles[i]*pi/180))
```

pi is a built in constant in R

Comment: Thanks! That did it.
Is there any way to control the length of the lines?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked to do exactly what I want:

```
for (i in 1:8) {
  i == 1
  segments(0,0, x1 = 2*cos(circumplex.angles[i]*pi/180), 
                y1 = 2*sin(circumplex.angles[i]*pi/180))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more generic solution, and an example image.

```
angles <- c(0, 45, 90, 180, 270) # in degrees
x0 <- 4
y0 <- 4
lineLength <- 2

plot(x0, y0, xlim=c(1, 8), ylim=c(1, 8), pch=15, cex=3)

for (i in 1:length(angles)) {
    x1 <- x0 + lineLength * cos(angles[i] * pi / 180)
    y1 <- y0 + lineLength * sin(angles[i] * pi / 180)
    
    segments(x0, y0, x1, y1, lwd=i)
    
    
    x1 <- x0 + (lineLength * 1.3) * cos(angles[i] * pi / 180)
    y1 <- y0 + (lineLength * 1.3) * sin(angles[i] * pi / 180)

    text(x1, y1, labels=angles[i])
    
}
```

[image]